# App showing "NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions" on pre 19 API in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

When starting the app in jellybean or lower version API, gradle giving this error.

```
09-05 03:53:20.660 6775-6775/com.example.MyApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4879)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4485)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4425)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My gradle.app is

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0' // Tried with and without this
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Checked each and every solutions provided in stack over flow but didn't worked.

My Google repositories and Google Play Services are updated.

Comment: do you have added this apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
to end of app build file?

Comment: Also show us which *apply:plugin* you have used in your *gradle* post that also.

Comment: no I didn't added that, I tried it, but it was showing that there in no .json file in app level or src level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this attribute to the application tag in manifest:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

remove `multiDexEnabled true` from gradle.

Comment: Great. It worked perfectly, but without removing `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: Hey @Karandeep can you explain what it does?

Comment: it will help you https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html